# Scala: value split is not a member of char

Tags: scala, mapping

I am trying to write word count program in Scala. I'm using a string `"file"` :

```
file.map( _.split(" ")).flatMap(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey( _ + _ )
```

It is keep saying that:

> value split is not a member of Char

Can't figure out how to solve it!

Comment: Why are you using `.map` with `.split` instead of `.split` directly? Map operates on the individual characters of the String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `map` on a `String` it is wrapped with `WrappedString` which extends `AbstractSeq[Char]`. Therefore, when you call `map` it is as if you are doing so on a `Seq` of `Char` not a `Seq` of `String`.

See the link below for the code https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.scala

The code below splits by whitespace and returns the size, a word counter.

```
val file = "Some test data"
file.split("\\s+").size
```

To get a count of the number of times each word in the string appears.

```
val file = "Some test data test"
println(file.split("\\s+").toList.groupBy(w => w).mapValues(_.length))
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped me but now I want to reduceByKey! and it gives me error which says : reduceByKey is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Int] .I added : .reduceByKey( _ + _ )

Comment: The reason you get that error is because there is no such method. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map for reference.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am running my program on spark using spark context. when I put it there I don't have any errors anymore but I need to figure out why the data is incorrect!

Comment: That clarifies things. I see the Spark homepage has your example. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the code is perfect! Just because I was running it on Spark, the answer was kept in lazy RDD file that I needed to collect it somehow. Therefore, I saved it to a text file and problem solved! Here is the code:

file.flatMap(line=>line.split(" ")).map(w=>(w,1)).reduceByKey(*+*).saveAsTextFile("OUT.txt")

Thanks.